# How do i upload a photo from the Android camera with FormData on Ionic / Angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, multipartform-data

I'm currently developing a Android app where the user can take his or hers picture and upload it to a PATCH API endpoint that would listen to the key 'avatar'.

I'm using the [Cordova Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) and the [Advanced HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) plugin to handle it.

Below is the function that triggers when taking a photo.

```
takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true,  // Corrects Android orientation quirks
      allowEdit: false, // Post process aanpassingen
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA // Pak de selfie camera
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('avatar', imageData, 'pic.jpg');
      this.web.updateUserInfo(formData).subscribe(() => {});
    }, (err) => {
      console.error('Camera Error: ' + err);
    });
  }
```

Here is the API handling

```
updateUserInfo(newData: any) {
        return new Observable((obs) => {
                this.http2.patch('localhost/user', {newData}, {
                    'X-Subdomain': 'host',
                    'X-Token': this.apiKey,
                }).then(() => {console.log('Camera API success!'); obs.next(); }).catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        });
    }
```

No errors are being given out so it is hard for me to see where the issue is. I have little experience working with Cordova and Ionic so this is all new to me.

Comment: Application side everything is working fine then. Cordova camera gives you the base64 of image. You have to debug on you server side or where you want to show your image.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is  `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,`

you are sending, file url over http and not the **base64** of image

Change your destination type:
`destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,`

**DATA_URL** Return base64 encoded string. DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI if possible

**UPDATE**

In this video you can check how to send **base64** to api as **File**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tph5Nk4Ab1g

Comment: Do I need to put this Base64 string in formData.append as well like how it currently goes? When checking Swagger for the API details, the API requires Parameter Type: FormData with Data Type: file.